Scroll Distance Tracker with Sticky Element Transitioning Issue
I am trying to achieve this functionality:
When the user scrolls the webpage from top to bottom, the moment it reaches the .test container, the .test should become sticky.
When the .test container is scrolled 80% to 100%, it should transition to a non-sticky position.
When .test is sticky at the top (position 0), only the .test container should scroll, and body scrolling should be inactive. Body scrolling should be re-enabled when the .test container is scrolled 80% to 100%.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const testElement = document.querySelector(".test");
  const body = document.body;

  // Function to check if the test element is at the top of the viewport
  function checkStickyPosition() {
    const rect = testElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top === 0) {
      testElement.classList.remove("scroll-stop-test");
      body.classList.add("scroll-stop-body");
    } else {
      testElement.classList.add("scroll-stop-test");
      body.classList.remove("scroll-stop-body");
    }
  }

  // Scroll event listener for the .test element to remove stickiness based on scroll percentage
  testElement.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrollTop = testElement.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = testElement.scrollHeight;
    const clientHeight = testElement.clientHeight;

    const scrollPercentage =
      (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100;

    if (scrollPercentage >= 80 && scrollPercentage <= 100) {
      testElement.style.position = "relative"; // Make it relative once fully scrolled
      testElement.style.top = "0px"; // Keep it at the top position
      body.classList.remove("scroll-stop-body");

      console.log("Scroll inside test element completed");
    }
  });

  // Scroll event listener for the window to check the sticky position
  window.addEventListener("scroll", checkStickyPosition);

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    checkStickyPosition();

    const rect = testElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top > 0) {
      testElement.style.position = "sticky";
      testElement.style.top = "0px";
      testElement.scrollTop = 0; // Scroll to the top
      body.style.position = "";
    }
  });

  // Initial check
  checkStickyPosition();
});
body {
  height: 2000px;
  /* Just to create a scrollable page */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test {
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 800px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 900px;
}

.scroll-stop-test {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-stop-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 2px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Scroll Distance Tracker</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="content">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>



Issues I am Facing:
With the condition rect.top > 0, whenever the .test container becomes sticky, the other content of the page (e.g., the .line div) changes position on the page. Its position varies depending on the scrolling speed. If I scroll very fast, the content goes under the .test div.
The .test container moves a few pixels upwards when it transitions from sticky to relative position.
How can I fix these issues?

Based on the description, sounds like this might be beneficial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API  thresholds can also be declared which could coincide with your "scroll percent". Hope this helps

Try these changes to your css and JavaScript,
For the JavaScript, the .test element becomes sticky when it reaches the top of the viewport and changes to a relative position when scrolled 80% to 100%. And It also manages the body’s overflow behavior to prevent body scrolling when the .test element is sticky.
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 800px;
  height: 500px; /* Match the height of .test */
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px; /* Add more content to make the .test scrollable */
}

.scroll-stop-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 2px;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const testElement = document.querySelector(".test");
  const body = document.body;

  function checkStickyPosition() {
    const rect = testElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top <= 0 && rect.bottom > window.innerHeight) {
      body.classList.add("scroll-stop-body");
    } else {
      body.classList.remove("scroll-stop-body");
    }
  }

  testElement.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrollTop = testElement.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = testElement.scrollHeight;
    const clientHeight = testElement.clientHeight;

    const scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100;

    if (scrollPercentage >= 80 && scrollPercentage <= 100) {
      testElement.style.position = "relative";
      testElement.style.top = "0px";
      body.classList.remove("scroll-stop-body");
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("scroll", checkStickyPosition);

  // Initial check
  checkStickyPosition();
});

Hope that helps :)
